# What does this SharedPreferences code do in Android?

Tags: java, android

I understand what SharedPreferences do but still struggling to get my head round what this piece of code is trying to do.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

if (sharedPref.getBoolean("login", false)) {

    edtUser.setText(sharedPref.getString("user", ""));
    edtPass.setText(sharedPref.getString("pass", ""));

    new SigninTask().execute("user=" + edtUser.getText(), "pass=" + edtPass.getText());
}
```

I understand that the first line is accessing the default SharedPreferences file. However I am still confused, what does this set code do exactly?. What information is it trying to get?. What does the last line do? (new SigninTask())..

Comment: The line new SigninTask().execute () creates a new instance of the SigninTask class that extends AsyncTask and makes the call to tell it that it should begin executing, the variables inside the execute call are parameters to pass to the AsyncTask class to use during execution.

Answer (score 1):

`sharedPref.getString("user", "")` tries to get a preference with the key `user` from the SharedPreferences. If it's not found, it returns an empty String. This value is loaded to a Text control (I assume, since you didn't include the definition of `edtUser`).
The same is done with the value of `pass`, which probably represents a password.

Basically, this app probably stores in SharedPreferences the `user` and `password` that were entered by the user of the app in a previous launch of the app, so that the user doesn't have to enter them again every time the app is launched.

There should be additional code that would store the entered `user` and `pass` in the SharedPreferences, and store the `login` preference with the value `true`.

Comment: perfect. Also does the code         edtUser.setText(sharedPref.getString("user", ""));    gets the "user" infoo from the shared preff and store it inside of edtUser?

Comment: And the code   "user=" + edtUser.getText()   gets the data stored in edtUser?

Comment: Sorry one last thing. The code if (sharedPref.getBoolean("login", false)) . Does this check if the key login is false or true. It been false meaning there is no data inside of the login key?

Comment: @AndiodIB About the "user=" - yes. About the getBoolean, if it finds in SharedPreferences a "login" key with value of "true", it assumes it can find data for the "user" and "pass" keys. If it gets "false", it either means there is no value for this key in the SharedPreferences (which causes it to return the default value - false) or that the value is "false".

Comment: so if its false it won't execute the remaining code.